# Jenkins Views and Nested Views are missing

Tags: jenkins

We are using Jenkins 1.584 and Nested views 1.14. 
For some reason, many standard Views and Nested Views are not showing up, even that all the jobs in them are listed in the All tab.

Also, the All tab is appearing twice... not sure if it relates.

Someone also saw it? any idea...?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "not showing up" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not relevant. the reason for this problem is that the config.xml was somehow corrupted.